# Detect when curl file download is completed

Tags: curl, download, applescript, shell-exec

I am downloading a file using curl on shell script:

`do shell script "curl -f http://example.com/file -o ~/Desktop/file.doc"`

Is there a way to detect/catch if the file download is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do shell script` works synchronously.

The next code line is executed when the download is completed.